# Asterisk space in C - What does the additional white space mean?

Tags: c

I think that `*something` and `* something` are different.

What does the additional white space do?

occurs here -> `void * malloc( size_t number_bytes );`

Comment: An asterisk with a space...? You need to be more specific. Where is this occurring? What are you doing in your code?

Comment: What!? Are you talking about difference between `char* someWord` and `char *someWord` (in which case, there is none)?

Comment: It is an indication that you should probably consult [a good introductory book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This is a newbie question, but to be fair, the "declaration reflects use" convention in C for pointers and dereference operators is quite confusing when you first learn it. I don't think the down votes were justified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, why is the asterisk before the variable name, rather than after the type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/), [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int* foo == int *foo == int * foo == int  *   foo
```

The whitespace does not make any difference to the compiler.

Comment: this is what I call a true example

Comment: I didn't downvote, but given this is a noob question, you may want to avoid the use of `==` in that context as it is not valid syntax and could confuse learners.

Answer (score 10):

When you use an asterisk to get the value of an address it is called the [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator). For example:

```
int x = *something;
```

In the example in your question the asterisk has a different meaning because it is part of a type, not part of an expression. It is used to specify that the return type is a pointer (in your specific example, a void pointer).

The extra space does not mean anything and is ignored by the compiler. It is there only to aid readability.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` operator in a declaration *always* binds to the declarator; the line

```
void * malloc (size_t number_bytes);
```

is parsed *as though* it had been written

```
void (*malloc(size_t number_bytes));
```

It's an accident of C syntax that you can write `T *p;` or `T* p;` or even

```
T             *                     p;
```

but all of them are parsed as `T (*p);` -- the whitespace makes no difference in how the declarations are interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

C ignores extraneous whitespace, so `"* "` should have the same effect as `"*"`.

If you want more clarification, please post a code example.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing, but with some whitespace added.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on [Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Those two lines do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `void * malloc(...)` example, `void *` is the type. `malloc` returns a pointer to void, which is just a pointer that needs to be cast to a particular type in order to be useful.