# difference between int* i and int *i

Tags: c, delphi

I'm converting a header file for a DLL written in C to Delphi so I can use the DLL.

My question is what is the difference between

```
int* i
```

and

```
int *i
```

I convert the first to

```
i: PInteger;
```

But i'm not sure what the correct conversion is for the second one in Delphi.

from my understanding the first is a simple typed pointer.
The second is a pointer variable. but i'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, why is the asterisk before the variable name, rather than after the type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/), [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`int* i` and `int *i` are completely equivalent

Comment: So the difference in the DLL header is a lack of consistency or a typo. thanks

Comment: If you're going to take the time to thank the guy, could you accept his answer, too?

Comment: sorry but I couldn't accept the answer straight away due to the question being answered so quickly. i got a msg telling me i can only accept the answer in 11 mins time

Comment: Also, and this is a cause for concern here at SO: When you accept an answer to a question, people stop viewing the question. I've noticed this several times. If I ask a question, and leave it open for a while, many people view it, and several will try to answer it. If I get a decent answer early on and accept it, there's a dramatic drop in viewers. There's also an abrupt stop in answers, so maybe there are even better answers to the question that will never surface. Food for thought...

Answer (score 72):

As far as C goes they both do the same thing. It is a matter of preference. `int* i` shows clearly that it is an int pointer type. `int *i` shows the fact that the asterisk only affects a single variable. So `int *i, j` and `int* i, j` would both create `i` as an int pointer and `j` as an int.

Comment: think I actually knew this already but its over 10 years since I did any C/C++ coding.

Comment: Din't you love those language quirks :-) I'm so glad I had completely forgotten about that, but it is good to see it noted somewhere with a high rating.

Answer (score 21):

They are the same.  The two different styles come from a quirk in C syntax.

Some people prefer `int* i;` because `int*` is the type of i.

Others prefer `int *i;` because the parser attaches the star to the variable, and not the type.  This only becomes meaningful when you try to define two variables on the line.  Regardless of how you write it:

```
 int* i,j;
 int*i,j;
 int *i,j;
```

in each of those, `i` is a pointer to an int, while j is just an int.  The last syntax makes that clearer, although, even better would be:

```
 int j, *i;
```

or best yet:

```
 int *i;
 int j;
```

Answer (score 16):

It's an accident of C syntax that you can write either `int *i` or `int* i` or even `int    *      i`.  All of them are parsed as `int (*i)`; IOW, the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.  This means that in declarations like

```
int* i, j;
```

only `i` is declared as a pointer; `j` is declared as a regular int.  If you want to declare both of them as pointers, you would have to write

```
int *i, *j;
```

Most C programmers use `T *p` as opposed to `T* p`, since a) declarations in C are expression-centric, not object-centric, and b) it more closely reflects declaration syntax.

As an example of what I mean by expression-centric, suppose you have an array of pointers to int and you want to get the integer value at element `i`.  The expression that corresponds to that value is `*a[i]`, and the *type* of the expression is `int`; thus, the declaration of the array is

```
int *a[N];
```

When you see the phrase "declaration mimics use" with regard to C programming, this is what is meant.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. You could type it as `int * i` if you wanted; they all mean the same thing: "i is a pointer to an int."

Answer (score 3):

`int* i`, `int * i`, `int*i`, and `int *i` are all exactly equivalent.  This stems from the C compiler (and it's compatible C like systems) ignoring white space in token stream generated during the process of parsing the source code.

Some people prefer to use `int* i` thinking that it makes the code cleaner (as the pointer directive is seen as part of the type in their minds).  Some people prefer to use `int *i` thinking that it makes the code cleaner (as the type is an int, and they have an "i pointer" to it).  Neither technique actually does anything differently after the compiler runs through the source code.  When in doubt, mimic the existing style.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing.

Some developers prefer the `int* i` notation because this way the type of i is clearly "pointer to an int" whereas `int *i` seems less readable.

Comment: I am curious why you think the latter is less readable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Points mentioned above highlight cases where "Type *" makes the most sense.

But a case where I personally found "Type*" makes intuitive sense/is more readable is when passing a reference to a pointer type. It is non-intuitive to a beginner when reading a variable as :

`int *&x; // what is x here ?`

as opposed to :

`int* (&x); // A reference to a int* type`

Answer (score 0):

It is different as:

1. When you want to declare many pointers on one line without writing * every time then you can use
   int* a,b,c,d;
   Here, a,b,c,d will all be pointers to integer
2. When you want to declare a pointer and a normal variable in one line, you must use
   int *a,*b,c,d;
   Here, a and b are pointers to integer, c and d are integer variables.

Comment: "Here, a,b,c,d will all be pointers to integer" is wrong, only the var 'a' will be a pointer. So, it is better put the asterisk before the var name than next to the data type, to avoid confusion.