# Difference between char* var; and char *var;?

Tags: c, pointers, ansi-c

Just wondering if there's any difference between:

```
char* var;
char *var;
```

or is it just a matter of preference (spacing)?

Comment: They are equivalent declarations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770187/difference-between-int-i-and-int-i

Comment: it's just a matter of preference, char *x is often used

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no difference in this case. However, you should prefer `char *var;`.

This is because the `*` is associated more closely with the variable name and is **not part of the base type**.  For example, if you do this:

```
char* a, b;
```

What you have is `a`, a pointer-to-`char`, and `b`, a `char`.  This is confusing!  Since the `*` character is closer to the `char` keyword, we expect that the types of both variables will be pointer-to-`char`, but the `*` is actually associated *only* with `a`.  (This is similar to `char a[10], b;` as pointed out by teppic in the comments; the `[10]` specifier is likewise only associated with `a`, and so only `a` will be an array.)

The correct declaration would be:

```
char *a, *b;
```

Putting the `*` specifier closer to the variable means that it's easy to see what's going on when you *intend* for one variable to be a pointer and the other not:

```
char *a, b;
```

In this case it's obvious that `b` was not intended to be a pointer.  In the original example (`char* a, b;`), we don't know whether or not the programmer intended for `b` to be a pointer.  To borrow from Douglas Crockford, all we know is that the programmer is incompetent.

Some people like to put a space before and after the `*`:

```
char * a, * b;
```

This falls prey to the same problem illustrated above: if `b` is not a pointer then the declaration (`char * a, b;`) may also lead to uncertainty about the programmer's intent.  Therefore I suggest not placing a space between the `*` and the variable name<sup>1</sup>.

Any way you look at it, `char* var;` should be treated as bad style.  It's grammatically correct according to the language specification, but leads to unreadable code because it *appears* to indicate that the `*` specifier is part of the type shared by all variables in the same declaration, when it is not.  (It's akin to writing a complex function all on the same line -- it works, but it's a bad idea.  There are cases where readability and maintainability supersede personal stylistic preferences, and this is one of them.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Personally, I prefer to put a space after the `*` *only* when dealing with function return values:

```
char * foo();
```

This is unambiguous: it's a function that returns a pointer-to-`char`.

```
char *foo();
```

Did the programmer mean a function that returns a pointer-to-`char`, or did he mean to create a pointer to a function that returns `char`?  The language will resolve this as identical to the other prototype, but our goal is readability, and that means conveying exactly what we mean to *humans*, not just the compiler.

Comment: It's also useful to compare the association of [] to define an array, and () to define a function. Although these follow the identifier, it's the same principle as defining a pointer with *.

Comment: @teppic Good point, those specifiers also behave the same way. The behavior of `*` makes a bit more sense when you consider those.

Comment: I also like the `char *var` style because in my opinion it makes the semantic meaning of `*` more consistent. `char *var` implies that the type of the *dereferenced* value pointed at by `var` is `char`, which is true. `char* var` looks like you put the dereference operator on the wrong side of the variable-name `char`, which doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I completely agree about the 'correct' way, I see that its also used the same way in my K&R C Book.. thank you for help! :D

Comment: +1 and more if I could -- you covered all the issues very well.

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation and the base type point. But multiple declaration per line are what's bad (especially when used with initialization like `int i, j = 0;`.) So the proper fix IMO would be to have multiple lines with one declaration each, rather than to change formatting (which his a matter of taste). The compiler can catch errors a lot better than the human eye.

Comment: @TemplateRex *"The compiler can catch errors a lot better than the human eye."* I will grant you this, but that's not at all the point of my answer. The point is not to avoid errors (both declaration forms are syntactically correct!) but to **convey intent to humans.** Don't make the next maintainer have to guess what we meant.