# Differences between pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

Is there any differences between these two declarations?

```
int* a;
int *a;
```

Or these two declarations are the same (pointer to an integer)?

Comment: Well, what did your beginner C book say?

Comment: They are exactly the same declaration as far as the C compiler is concerned. It's a matter of style and personal preference which variant to use.

Comment: I'm not exactly a C beginner. I'm asking that because gcc was giving me a warning when I was using the first style with a struct.

Comment: @Guilherme. Most definitely the issue was somewhere else. Or you ran into the problem stated in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're exactly the same, but here's a small gotcha I came across when first learning C years ago. The * binds to the *variable*, not the type. This means that

```
int* a, b;
```

Declares `a` as a pointer to int, and `b` as an *int*. To declare both as pointers, one should do.

```
int *a, *b;
```

This is why I prefer to place the `*` next to the name.

Comment: more here ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212126/difference-between-char-var-and-char-var

Comment: @JoeDF Strangely enough, those are my exact same notation conventions! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm asking that because gcc was giving me a warning when I was using "struct foo* pointer" declaration.