# Invalid type argument of ->. Help me understanjd pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, variable-declaration

So I am learning pointers and i think I mostly understand how they work but Im still learning how to use them correctly.

I wrote this code that receives a pointer to a list with pointers innit, each pointing to a struct called Data.
I wanted to organize them by number, like say i have [29-10, 28-10, 3-1] the outcome would be [ 3-1; 2-10; 29-10 ]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
} Data;

void organiza(Data** l, int n)
{
    Data* aux, d1, d2;
    int j, i;
    for (i = 0;i<n-1;i++ )
    {
        for (j= i + 1;j<n;j++)
        {
            d1 = l[i];
            d2 = l[j];
            if (d1->mes > d2-> mes || (d1->mes == d2-> mes && d1->dia >= d2-> dia ))
            {
                aux == d1;
                d1 == d2;
                d2 == aux;
            }
        }
                
    }
}
```

While doing so I got a lot of errors which I dont understand why are happening:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Data’ {aka ‘struct ’} from type ‘Data *’ {aka ‘struct  *’}
d1 = l[i];
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Data’ {aka ‘struct ’})
 if (d1->mes > d2-> mes || (d1->mes == d2-> mes && d1->dia >= d2-> dia ))
```

Comment: `Data* aux, d1, d2;` should be `Data *aux, *d1, *d2;`

Comment: `Data* aux, d1, d2;` is equivalent to `Data *aux, d1, d2;`, and that might make it much clearer that only `aux` is a pointer, not `d1` or `d2`. This is one reason why I personally tend to define or declare only one variable per statement, where such mistakes are harder to make.

Comment: This is a good [example of why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770938/2505965) `int *foo` is generally preferred  over `int* foo` in C.

Comment: In C syntax terms, `Data` is the *type-specifier*, and `* aux, d1, d2` is a list of three *declarator*s. `d1` and `d2` are *direct-declarator*s. `* aux` is a *pointer* followed by a *direct-declarator*. They could be declared in a different order: `Data d1, d2, *aux;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case

```
Data* aux, d1, d2;
```

means, `aux` is a pointer, `d1` and `d2` are not. You need to write

```
Data *aux, *d1, *d2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
Data* aux, d1, d2;
```

is equivalent to

```
Data (* aux ), d1, d2;
```

or as the same

```
Data* aux;
Data d1, d2;
```

That is the variables `d1` and `d2` have the type `Data`.

So for example in these statements

```
d1 = l[i];
d2 = l[j];
```

the left operands have the type `Data` but the right operands of the assignments have the type `Data *` because the variable `l` has the type `Data **` due to its declaration

```
void organiza(Data** l, int n)
              ^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to declare the variables `d1` and `d2` as pointers then you need to write

```
Data *aux, *d1, *d2;
```