# Would this be a valid declaration?

Tags: c, pointers

Will this correctly declare one an integer and another as an pointer to an integer or will this just cause problems?

```
int *countPtr, count;
```

Comment: Woosh. What he's saying is: It does "correctly declare one an integer and another as an pointer to an integer", but it also causes problems because it's stupid and confusing that it does this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type

Answer (score 3):

It is a valid declaration, it will compile.

However, it can lead to confusion, so it's safer to declare it separately:

```
int count;
int *countPtr;
```

For increased readability, you can keep in mind this simple rule:

**Don't mix types in one declaration.**

You don't want to see nightmares like `int x, y, *p, t[10], i, f();`.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this correctly declare one an integer and another as an pointer to an integer?

Yes.

> Will this just cause problems?

Yes.  Declarations of multiple types on a single line (especially when pointers are involved as in your example) is heavily discouraged, for the obvious readability/maintenance issues.

Comment: @user2172993: I disagree with Oli - it would only be confusing if you followed the C++-style `T* p` convention, which you aren't doing in this case. For anyone who's been programming in C for more than ten minutes, it's clear which is the pointer and which isn't.

Comment: @JohnBode: I've seen grimness like `int x, foo(), *p;` in real code.  So I'll stick to my belief that mixing types on a single line is nasty ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is completely fine.

- `countPtr` will be a pointer to int
- `count` will be just regular int

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a valid statement and will work as expected.

Writing

```
int* countPtr, count
```

would do the same thing, but can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
Will this correctly declare one an integer and another as an pointer?
```

Absolutely.

```
will this just cause problems?
```

Programically speaking, No. Readability-wise, Depends on how you interpret the declaration `int *countPtr, count;`. I read it as "integer-holder countPtr and integer count". So no problems for me.