# Difference between func(int& x) and func(int &x) in C++

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to learn the basics of C++. The book I'm reading uses the following syntax:

```
func(int& x);
```

On the internet, I mostly see the following syntax:

```
func(int &x);
```

Both seem to do exactly the same. Is there any difference?

Comment: People have coding standards - some prefer the former rather than the latter. But no difference

Comment: You've never seen `func(int & x);`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have now. :-)

Comment: @david Sure, but what about `func(int      &      x);`?  (ok ok, now that [isn't valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bae8c132740539c2))

Comment: @Yakk That code had no spaces. A version with spaces [will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9aa257bee6e3317b).

Comment: @memo1288 It has lots of spaces!  They where just not the spaces C++ was expecting to consume.  (In order for multiple spaces to show up in a comment here, you have to use a non-standard space, which isn't valid C++)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Literally no difference. Just a stylistic preference. The [same is true of where you put the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type).

Comment: Although you'll read about it if you click through to your link, perhaps you should add here the bit about being mislead to believe adding the asterisk next to the type makes all of the variables pointers.

Comment: @DavidVereb: Or just do as Bjarne recommends: "Declaring one name per declaration minimizes the problem".

Comment: "Just a stylistic preference" – not only, it's also about emphasis.

Comment: @zenith ... which would be a style preference. As far as the compiler cares, they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to the [Is `int* p;` right or is `int *p;` right?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) FAQ on Bjarne Stroustrup's website. It's for pointers, but what he writes equally holds for references:

> Both are "right" in the sense that both are valid C and C++ and both
>   have exactly the same meaning. [...] The choice between `int* p;` and `int *p;` is not about right and wrong, but about style and emphasis.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer `int& x`. This way the reference becomes part of the type, it's an "int reference" called x, instead of "int, reference of x"

I find that thinking of "int reference" as a discrete type makes it less confusing, but to the compiler it's the same thing.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, this is merely providing your opinion/preference.

Comment: @CoryKramer I'm already thinking about closing the question as _"opinion based"_ or finding a good duplicate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question itself is not opinion-based per se. The answer to their question is "no there isn't a difference". It does seem that there are some duplicates, or at least very closely related questions.

Comment: It does answer it actually and gives some background why one way is (slightly) better (in my opinion).

Comment: @ventsyv: The ampersand doesn't become part of the type. Given `int& a, b;` are both `a` and `b` references?

Comment: @Blastfurnace That's unfortunate artifact due to backward compatibility with C which binds the ampersand to the name but putting the emphasis on "a of type X" (being int& or int* or whatever) is still beneficial. The multi variable declaration is confusing no matter where you put the ampersand.

Comment: The question gets answered. Final line, "...but to the compiler it's the same thing."
It does however provide a human-read syntax as to why you might use it one way vs the other.
Suggested edit: Restate the same thing with the answer first, and then why you'd use it in different circumstances.