# Why is the asterisk in a pointer declaration specific to the identifier and not the data type?

Tags: c, pointers, types, syntax

Silly question, but trying to grasp the underlying mechanics/philosophy to solidify my understanding.

```
int myInt; // declares a variable of type integer, named myInt. Intuitive.
int* myPtr; // declares a variable of type pointer-to-integer. Also intuitive.

int myInt2, myInt3; // two more integer variables.. yay!! This makes sense.
// so the pattern is [type] [identifier] <,more-identifiers>;

int* myInt4, myInt5; // an int pointer then an integer. Brain hurts!
```

Comment: Your brain hurts because you insist on using a style that's not consistent with the language.

Comment: It should be `int *myPtr;` and `int *myInt4, myInt5;`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/398414/125507

Comment: I should note that I've been coding in C++ for quite some time, and finally stumbled into this weirdness in the language. I've always left-aligned the asterisk because I think the pointer is part of the type. And it *is*! You can pass `int*` into templates, and `int*` can be the type of something. The only place this doesn't apply, afaik, is in variable declarators, where the pointer is part of the identifier! Even then, it's invisible if you only declare one variable. I get that it's because C works that way, but I think some brain-hurting is justified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR - that is how C syntax is designed to work.

The `*` is considered *attached* to the variable, because, it *defines* the type of the variable, not the *datatype*. The type of an object is supposed to be a property of the object itself, so it makes sense to consider the *identifier* of the property is associated with the object(variable).

To clarify, by saying `int * p;`, we mean to say, `p` is a variable of type *pointer* which points to an `int`. So, it makes sense to attach the `*` to the variable, rather than to the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of answer are you expecting? This is just how C works. If you don't like it, Bjarne Stroustrup (creator of C++) agrees with you, and recommends to avoid doing the thing you did in the last line.

It makes sense to the makers of C, and also, its common to put the `*` next to the variables rather than next to the type so that it's less confusing:

```
int *myInt4, myInt5; // an int pointer then an integer.
```

If you use `clang-format` to format your source-code, this is style-option `PointerAlignment`, and the option you want is `PAS_Right` for that.

Answer (score 0):

`int* myInt4, myInt5`; // an int pointer then an integer. Brain hurts!

This is just style, compiler will interpret it correctly. 
Theoretically, You can put * any where.

```
 Type* variable;
 Type * variable;
 Type *variable;
```

And It can be read as:

`int* myInt4, myInt5`;` // A pointer variable (myInt4) and a variable (myInt5) of type int.