# Void parameter in function

Tags: c, function, parameters

In Andrew Carter's implementation of the [Blowfish](https://www.schneier.com/academic/blowfish/download.html) cipher, one function takes the parameter `*keyparam` and copies it to the variable `*key`.

```
void blowfish_initiate(blowfish_context_t *ctx, void *keyparam, unsigned int keybytes)
{
    keybytes %= 57;
    unsigned char *key = keyparam;  // How is this possible?
    int i, j, k;
    unsigned long calc;

    // ...code...

    if(keybytes) {
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            for(k = 0, calc = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                calc <<= 8, calc |= key[j++];
                if(j == keybytes)
                    j = 0;
            }
            ctx->pbox[i] ^= calc;
        }
    }

    // ...code...
}
```

How is this possible if `keyparam` is `void`?

I know functions can have void parameters, but can they be used?

Comment: It's not a `void`, it's a `void *`.

Comment: 'keyparam' is not `void`, `void *`! Typically in programming languages, symbols are not just for decoration.

Comment: So, `void *` can be any type?

Comment: to add to what Ian said. `void*` is a special pointer type that any pointer can be cast to or from (whether correctly or incorrectly is up to you, but the compiler sure doesn't care).

Comment: Is `void* keyparam` is the same as `void *keyparam`?

Comment: @54696D yes, they are same.

Comment: In this case, it would be better if the parameter were `const void *keyparam`, since the function does not modify the thing that keyparam points to. (I know the post has ellipsis-ed out some code, but I've seen other versions of this function that do not modify the keyparam either.)

Comment: @54696D see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758367/2173917) for a discussion. disclaimer; my answer. :)