# "error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant" is coming up to my code

Tags: c, function, average

The program is about function making an average. I get an error:

> error: expected ';', ',' or ') before numeric constant

within the avg_array() function whenever I build it. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#define SIZE 5

// Prototypes
int avg_array (int*, int);          

main()
{
    int values[SIZE];
    int avg;
    int i;

    printf("Enter 5 numbers please. \n");

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {   
        scanf("%d", &values[i]);
    }

    avg = avg_array(values, SIZE);
    printf("\n The avg of the array is %d \n", avg);

    getchar();
    getchar();
} // end main()


/* Implement avg_array() WHERE THE ERROR PERTAINS */
avg_array(int my_array[], int SIZE)
{
    int sum;
    int i;
    int fxn_average;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + my_array[i];
    }

    fxn_average = (sum/SIZE);

    return (fxn_average);
}
```

Comment: Any particular line you're getting that error on?

Comment: It looks like he tried to put `**  **` around the troublesome part (as if to boldface it with SO's formatting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the identifier `SIZE` as an argument.  This is also a macro that gets converted to `5` by the preprocessor.  After the preprocessor applies the macros, it would look like

```
avg_array (int my_array[], int 5)
```

Since `5` is a numeric constant instead of an identifier, it generates an error.  Change the variable name.

It looks like you also have a function signature missing a return type, which should match the prototype declared above.  Try this instead:

```
int avg_array (int *my_array, int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       sum = sum + my_array[i];
    }
    return sum/size;
}
```

The variable `sum` should be initialized to 0.  The local variable `fxn_average` is not needed because you can use just `return sum/size;` at the end instead.

---

I changed the type of the first argument from `int[]` (array of `int`) to `int *` (pointer to `int`) so the function *definition* matches the prototype given in the question. The function was *declared* as

```
int avg_array (int*, int);
```

These arguments have no identifiers; only their types are specified.  This is valid C, but many style guides prescribe against it since naming arguments helps the reader understand meaning or intent.  If you are writing a programming interface, for example, all the programmer will likely see is the function prototypes in a header file.  It must be clear what the arguments are to write a correct function call.  Anyway, adding in identifiers looks like:

```
int avg_array (int *my_array, int size);
```

which is the same as in the *definition* I used above.

Comment: Thank you very much! One question though, why is there an asterisk BEFORE "my_array" when I already declared the indirection operator AFTER the pointer in the "int*"? You're a life saver!

Comment: I've added a bit that might answer your question, but I don't quite understand it. What do you mean by "declared the indirection operator AFTER the pointer in the 'int*'"? The asterisk in `int *my_array` is there because `int *` is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to programming. Thanks again for adding more information but I already get how the code works. I'm just a bit curious on why there is an asterisk on the pointer before on the code `int *MY_ARRAY` WHILE there is an asterisk on the pointer right after on the code `int avg_array (INT*, int);`. (pointer is on caps)

Comment: `int *p` is equivalent to `int* p` (both `p` are pointers to an `int`). Where you put the space doesn't matter.   You could also write without a space `int*x`. The `int *p` style is more common.  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type).

Comment: Ohh now I see! You're an angel!