# Why it is a const pointer rather than pointer to const?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, alias

In C++ Primer book, there is an explanation on type aliases as:

```
typedef char *pstring;
const pstring cstr = 0; // cstr is a constant pointer to char
```

They say that the following is a wrong interpretation:

```
const char *cstr = 0;
```

However it makes sense to me, to replace the typedef alias with its original meaning.

In a normal scenario without type aliasing a constant pointer is defined as:

```
char *const cstr = 0;
```

Why is it constant pointer rather than pointer to const?

Can anyone explain in clear terms because the book doesn't seem to clarify it much.

Comment: `const` binds to the thing to its immediate left (unless `const` is the first thing, in which case it binds to the thing to its immediate right).  Since `pstring` is a pointer, `const pstring` binds to the pointer.

Comment: `2 * 3 + 1` is 7. But how come if I do `int i = 3 + 1;` and then `2 * i` it gives 8? Shouldn't the variable be replaced with its original meaning?

Comment: Religious issue warning, but I find `const char* cstr = 0;` much more readable.  I only put asterisks on the left of things when I'm dereferencing them.

Comment: @immibis: What, if anything, does that have to do with this question?

Comment: The book suggests to use it to left of variable names. e.g. `int *ptr = 0, val = 0;` Here ptr is a pointer to int while val is an integer variable. @RobertHarvey

Comment: Like I said.  Religious issue.  I see the * as part of the type.

Comment: However, my question is still unanswered :(

Comment: `const` applies to *whatever the type is.*  In your case, the type is a pointer to a char.  That's why making the asterisk part of the type (and not part of the variable name) makes more sense, even though C doesn't care which style you use.

Comment: In any case, here is the opposing viewpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/q/398395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2 * 3 + 1` is 7. But how come if I do `int i = 3 + 1;` and then `2 * i` it gives 8? Shouldn't the variable be replaced with its original meaning?

It's because `2 * 3 + 1` is interpreted as `(2 * 3) + 1`, while `2 * i` is the same as `2 * (3 + 1)`. These mean different things and work out to different numbers. When you give `3 + 1` a name, when you use the name it doesn't break up the number back into `3 + 1` in order to only multiply the 3.

The reason that `const char *` is different from `const pstring` is very similar. `const char *` is interpreted as `(const char) *` i.e. a pointer to a constant char. But `const pstring` is the same as `const (char *)` i.e. a constant pointer to a char. `pstring` is a whole type by itself, and when you do `const pstring` it doesn't split up the `char *` in order to make the `char` part const.

Note: if you did `#define pstring char *` then `const pstring` *would* be the same as `const char *`, because macros (`#define`s) are just treated as text replacements.

Comment: I still don't see what your math has to do with any of this.

Comment: Shouldn't `const (char *)` be explained as constant pointer rather than pointer to a constant char?? @immibis

Comment: You don't see the analogy between `(2 * 3) + 1` and `2 * (3 + 1)` and `(const char) *` and `const (char *)`? Oh well. Hopefully someone else does.

Comment: From your answer: `const char *` is interpreted as `(const char) *` **i.e. a pointer to a const char**. But const pstring is the same as `const (char *)` **i.e. a pointer to a constant char**. How can they both mean pointer to a constant char? @immibis

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it's a good analogy. You can't split an expression and its sub-expressions into its tokens and then inspect arbitrary groups of them to determine the result.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: But it's not an *expression* at all; it's a *declaration.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are both sequences of tokens that represent things. In both cases a thing represented by a sequence of tokens may be given a name which is also a token. You can't split a token-sequence and its sub-token-sequences into its tokens and then inspect arbitrary groups of them to determine the result. It doesn't matter which words you use - the abstract concept is the same and is equally valid.