# What's the difference between (int *pointer) and (int* pointer)

Tags: c, function, pointers

While passing pointer to a function in C, on the receiving end, two conventions are seen:

```
void foo(int *pointer)
```

and

```
void foo(int* pointer)
```

What's the difference between them?

Comment: No difference at all. You can even write `int * pointer`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type