# What is the difference between Object* myObject and Object *myObject

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't own a book on C++ and cant afford one, and cant seem to find a decent post (or a good google result) regarding the topic.

So what is the difference? and what would best practice be for writing this?

`Object*     myObject;`

vs.

`Object      *myObject`

Comment: Personal preference

Comment: Here's a round about answer as well as explaining a gotcha that can come from this confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type

Comment: in general whitespace in c++ is ignored

Comment: [This is a little bit out of date](https://isocpp.org/tour) and it's terse as hell but if you have and cannot get a reputable C++ text, it's better than nothing. The information is high quality, it's just hard to parse and light on explanation. Use it in conjunction with the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and you'll have an easier time.

Comment: As per [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#whitespace), Sutter & Stroustrup suggest the first one is preferential for C++.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a variable, these two are essentially the same. Best practices depend on your style guide, and when contributing to a larger codebase, consistency with existing style.

However, there's one subtlety that leads me to prefer the second option `Object *myObject` *in cases where this does not clash with an existing style guide*. Specifically, the following code declares an Object pointer, and an Object (**not** a pointer):

```
Object *obj1, obj2;
```

When the asterisk is attached to the name, this is a bit clearer - at a rapid glance, the following equivalent code could mislead someone (especially a newer programmer who isn't aware of this gotcha) into thinking two pointers are being declared:

```
Object* obj1, obj2;
```

Furthermore, I probably wouldn't recommend mixing types like this anyway, and if I did want to declare two pointers then

```
Object *obj1, *obj2; // declarations look consistent
```

seems a tad cleaner than

```
Object* obj1, *obj2; // need to use second style anyway
```

or

```
Object* obj1, * obj2; // ???
```