# Why is the asterisk used before the each variable name instead of after the type?

Tags: c, pointers

**This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type)**

I understand why it is better to declare variables like this:

```
int *var;
```

instead of

```
int* var
```

I understand that this avoids the ambiguous case of
`int* var1, var2` where it would seem that `var1` and `var2` are both pointers to integers, but var2 is actually just a regular integer.

My question is why `int* var1, var2` doesn't declare both variables as pointers to integers. Intuitively, I would think that `int*` would act like any other data type, where you would just have to use `int* var1, var2` to declare both variables of type `int*`. In other words, why is C designed so that each variable needs an asterisk before it?

Comment: It's how Java works (for arrays). Two different languages. To mitigate the ambiguity, better put `int *x;` and `int y;` on 2 different lines, if that pleases you.

Comment: If you think it's not a duplicate, then why does it have the **almost the exact title**? Either it's a duplicate, or you need to edit your title to ask a different question.,

Comment: I morbidly sense a long period of hiding pointer types in typedef aliases on the road ahead. I just pray you figure out sooner rather than later what a dreadful idea it is.

Comment: It's designed that way because the syntax appealed to Dennis Ritchie. We may never know why, unless his acquaintances from Bell Labs recall.

Comment: Consider `int *(*p)(int,int)`... p is a variable name. Oh! p is a pointer!... Oh! p is a pointer to a function (taking two args). Oh, p is a pointer to a function (taking two args) that returns a pointer... and that pointer points to an int. If you go with `int *p;`, the rest becomes much simpler...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html gives some insight into the reasoning. *the declaration of a variable resembles its usage in an expression whose type is the one named at the head of the declaration.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Intuitively, I would think that `int*` would act like any other data type

If you want to become comfortable with C, you may need to adjust your intuition!  Types are at least a little bit complicated; in fact the type system is a lot like a little programming language of its own!  `int` is a type, but "pointer" is a meta-type.  You can have pointers to anything, even pointers to pointers.

> In other words, why is C designed so that each [pointer] variable needs an asterisk before it?

Because, as explained in several of the answers to [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395), the scheme is that a declaration contains a "base type" and then some "declarators".  In the case of arrays, pointers, and functions, the "declarator" is a little sample of whatever thing is going to have the base type.  If I say

```
int i;
```

the declarator is just `i`, so I'm saying that `i` is going to be an `int`.  No mystery there.  But if I say

```
int a[10];
```

I'm saying that one element of the array I'm declaring — that is, when I later use the array by saying something like `a[i]` — is going to be an `int`.  If I say

```
int f();
```

I'm saying that calling the function is going to return an `int`.
Finally, if I say

```
int *ip;
```

I'm saying that when I take the contents of this pointer, using the expression `*ip`, then what `*ip` is going to be is an `int`.

And of course I can string these together on the same line:

```
int i, a[10], f(), *ip;
```

Now, perhaps I'm just rehashing the answers at the other question, and not explaining *why* things were set up this way.  The reason is that it makes it possible to declare arbitrarily-complicated derived types.  We can have arrays, and pointers, and functions, and arrays of arrays, and pointers to arrays, and functions returning pointers, and pointers to functions, and arrays of pointers to functions, and functions returning pointers to functions, and types even more numerous and complicated than those, and they can all be declared (in a general and open-ended way) using the same sort of concise, punctuation-rich, unwordy syntax that C is famous for

I don't think it would have been possible to design a type system that could have expressed the concept of "array of pointers to functions" on the left, leaving you to just put the variable name on the right.  Or, if you could design such a system, it would have been complicated and confusing and cumbersome to use, even more complicated and confusing than C's present scheme seems to you, with its odd combination of type names on the left, and declarators — with their mixture of names, asterisks, and other punctuation — on the right.

See also [Question 1.21](https://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html) in the [C FAQ list](https://c-faq.com/).

---

Or, perhaps I lied.  I just said, "I don't think it would have been possible to design a type system that could have expressed [complicated things] on the left, leaving you to just put the variable name on the right."  But, in fact, C's `typedef` facility lets you do precisely that, if you want to build up a complex type in stages.

For example, if you say

```
typedef int *pointer_to_int;
```

you have arranged that the identifier `pointer_to_int` is not an actual variable of type `int *`, but rather, a *synonym* for the type `int *`.  Having done that, you can declare several integer pointers at once, without having to re-type those pesky asterisks:

```
pointer_to_int p1, p2, p3;    /* just like int *p1, *p2, *p3; */
```

And it works for more complicated types, too.  I can say

```
typedef int *(*pointer_to_function_returning_pointer_to_int)();
```

and then do

```
 pointer_to_function_returning_pointer_to_int x1, x2, x3;
```

at which point `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are all pointers to functions returning pointers to `int`, just as if I'd said

```
int *(*x1)(), *(*x2)(), *(*x3)();
```

In fact, the CS50 course introduces a "handy" typedef

```
typedef char *string;
```

which makes the identifier `string` be an alias for the type "pointer to `char`", which allegedly makes it easier for beginners to declare lots of strings.  Unfortunately, `char *` isn't *really* C's One True String type, so the `string` typedef probably causes as much confusion as it attempts to resolve.  (Part of the problem is that pointers do not necessarily make good "opaque" types.  If you're dealing with a pointer, you often need to *know* that you're dealing with a pointer, so hiding it behind a typedef doesn't help.)