# Explanation of syntax of array of string pointers

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

An array of pointers to a string is defined as follows:

```
char *array[];
```

But this looks like an array of pointers to a single char. How is this an array of pointers to a string?

How does C know that the pointer is pointing to the first char of a string, and not to a single char?

Obviously this is incorrect, but why isn't the syntax something like this:

```
char[] *array[];
```

Which then looks like an array of pointers to an array of chars (a string).

Comment: Would it be more understandable [if it was](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398395/11683) `char* array[]`?

Comment: How does any `char*` know if it's a pointer to one character or many ?

Comment: @GSerg Wouldn't this then make more sense: ```char* *array[]```. ie. ```char **array[]```?

Comment: @Tom That [would be](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+**c%5B%5D) an array of `char**`, which is a different type than `char*`.

Comment: The syntax for an array of pointers to **whole** arrays of `char` would be `char (*array[])[]`. Though one never finds such types in practical code.

Answer (score 1):

> How does C know that the pointer is pointing to the first char of a string, and not to a single char?

He doesn't know it. It's up to the programmer to know that.
The syntax is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* ptr[2];

    char a = 'A';
    ptr[0] = &a;

    ptr[1] = "Hello!";

    putchar(*ptr[0]);
    puts(ptr[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The pointer can point to a char as well as to the first char of a character string.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to `char` references a single `char` but if this char is part of the string (array of `char`s) then it is referencing the strings. It is how the pointers are used.

C language also knows pointers to arrays.

```
char (*p)[20];
```

where `p` is an pointer to 20 elements `char` array.

You can also define array of such pointers, but it is I think too advanced topic.

Example: `char (*(*p)[10])[20]`

Answer (score 0):

In plain C an string is exactly the same as an array of characters.

The string needs to store every character in a byte in memory, in order. This is exactly how an array is structured.

> How is this an array of pointers to a string?

C is not as smart/advanced as other languages, it's a DIY language. Leaving all the power to the programmer.
So an pointer to an string is for the C compiler the same as an pointer to an single character, the only difference is, your allowed to access and modify the consecutive bytes as well.

An pointer to an array of integers, or an pointer to an single integer is also exactly the same for the C compiler.

> How does C know that the pointer is pointing to the first char of a string, and not to a single char?

Simply said, it doesn't but you, the programmer do know that this is an string.

And in C an string is terminated by an `'\0'` character. Thus every string in C actually looks like `"your long string\0"`.
Therefore C does know how to print the complete string when using `printf("%s",ptr_to_string);`

Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: An array of `char` is only a string if it has a valid `nul` terminator.